# Delete association fields in Rails 3.1 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

I am trying to make a nested model form in which I can add/delete association objects on the fly.

In Rails 3.0.x that would work properly if I created a hidden input with the "_destroy" name that when set to 1 it would have deleted the association record.

Now whenever I submit the form with the hidden input _destroy set to 1 (or true) it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write:

```
:allow_destroy => true
```

?

```
# model.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :model, :allow_destroy => true
# view
<%= f.fields_for :model do |fields| %>
...
Delete: <%= fields.check_box :_destroy %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Odd enough ... this isn't required in Rails 3.0.x .